# How can we convert the Word(*.doc/*.docx) to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, interop

I have a task to convert the word document to PDF file. I need some process which could be done for free.Could any help me the process of converting the Word to PDF file for free with out Microsoft Interop ?

Answer (score 2):

The sad truth is that you proberbly can't.
If it is a simple document with little styling and simple tables, or even less, then yes, you can proberbly find a free solution.

The paid solutions don't really work well either unless it's a somewhat simple document.
I was involved in a project where I made a document-generating system that had to prepare around 24.000 word documents in .docx and .pdf every day, and believe me we tried everything.

The free solution that almost kinda worked when the document did not contain any advances plots or tables was a java solution, [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j).

We tried using Apose, Gembox and a bunch of others, but none of them could transform the advanced documents to a proper pdf without messing up the formatting.

Try converting something like this: [example](http://www.byggeevaluering.dk/media/51313/noegletalsrapport_lang_ent_demo_2015.pdf) without using word. It won't work. Or at least it wouldn't approximately a year ago.

We ended up with setting up a dedicated document-server that hosts a very much abused Microsoft Word process that does nothing all day except generate and convert documents.

I would be very happy to discover the presence a decent free (or paid) alternativ. But my experience is that as soon as your document gets very complicated (see the example) no one knows .docx like Microsoft. And it sucks that they can't/won't just make a proper .dll you can include in your project for conversion, but that is the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only small doc and docx files, you could use the free version of: [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/)

If you want to convert your documents with all styles and so on, i think you have to buy a component. I've spent a lot of time searching for an open source solution, but could not find anything. GemBox.Document has a really good price/performance ratio.

Comment: But the convertapi is a paid service which needs to be used.